# can someone help me with this map format?

Tags: c++, file-format

I've been messing around in visual studio for half an hour trying to figure out how to properly display maps from a file, but all I can output is hot garbage, all I know is that the maps are 64x64, can someone help me with this?

[map file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E1hCQaqfR5at0pkKgbKuyt7RhMua9IYC/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must have been looking at the wrong representation.

Opening the file with a plain graphics viewer shows that it indeed contains "maps", in a 2-byte-per-block format and with a fixed width of 128 bytes/64 blocks:

[image: image courtesy of a most basic bitmap viewer]

The first 514 bytes seem to contain some other kind of data but after that every two bytes form one single map block. You'll have to compare these word values against a running game to find out what they represent.

Finding the bitmap text "D.P. Gray 1994" in the map leads me to believe you are looking at [Nitemare 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitemare_3D), and with that information you can find *several* map editors, such as the one at http://wolf3d.darkbb.com/t1981-nitemare-3d-mapeditor, which conveniently also tells you the same details I describe above (do note that that post is from 2011).

<sup>It took me less than 5 minutes to recognize "the format", and another 5 or so to google "D.P. Gray 1994".</sup>